# Random net disconnection while using actively on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I am using Kubuntu with KDE Plasma version 5.18.5.

My Wi-Fi keeps on dropping out even while I am actively using it. This happens only with the PC as my mobile works perfectly fine on the same Wi-Fi.

```
 description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 00:21:cc:b9:ea:fa
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:f3900000-f391ffff memory:f392b000-f392bfff ioport:6080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 3e
       serial: 24:77:03:44:b9:80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-74-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.43.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:34 memory:f3800000-f3801fff
On using **dmesg | grep -i firmware**, result is:
[    0.126605] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.159113] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.180136] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.652957] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[   15.340623] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.341099] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-6000-5.ucode failed with error -2
[   15.867976] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 9.221.4.1 build 25532 op_mode iwldvm
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: In terminal try `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwl-opt.conf && sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`  Then reboot and see if the dropouts happen with aggressive TX enabled and wifi power management disabled